# Python Custom List Class - Slicing Self

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, subclass

I have the following custom class that is intended to truncate itself when it is of length greater than 5. When stepping through the code, the slice operation DOES occur, but when control returns to the caller the stored topFiveList instance remains of length > 5. What am I doing incorrectly here?

```
class topFiveList(list):
    def add(self, key, value):
        index = -1
        for i, pair in enumerate(self):
            if pair[1] < value:
                index = i
                break
        if index == -1:
            self.append([key, value])
        else:
            self.insert(index, [key, value])
        if len(self) > 5:
            self = self[:5]

testvals = [['six', 6], ['one',1], ['five',5], ['nine', 9], ['three',3], ['four', 4], ['seven', 7]]
topFive = topFiveList()
for text, value in testvals:
    topFive.add(text, value)
```

Comment: `self = self[:5]` does not modify the `self` instance.

Comment: ok. but why doesn't it? and how do I change the self instance? and also, for whoever downvoted this question, can you please post a comment letting me know how I can improve the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self = self[:5]` does not modify the `self` instance, it simply binds the local variable `self` to the created slice `self[:5]`.

However, you could use slice assignment.

```
self[:] = self[:5]
```

and

```
self[5:] = []
```

both achieve the same.

The first option replaces the contents of `self` with `self[:5]`. OTOH the second option will simply remove everything starting from position 5.